# Not returning anything base64 decode

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, fs, cryptojs

I try to decrypt a file with crypto-js (in this file there is a long string of encrypted base64).
but I don't get anything back the file is empty and the log too.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

fs.writeFile("2pac.txt", decode(), (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  // success case, the file was saved
  console.log("Lyric saved!");
});

function decode() {
  // INIT
  const encoded = fs.readFileSync("./base64.txt", { encoding: "base64" });
  // PROCESS

  const decoded = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(encoded); // decode encodedWord via Utf8.stringify() '75322541'
  console.log(decoded);
  return decoded;
}
```

In the console.log I get the test but I don't get anything(even undefined).

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
const decoded = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(encoded);
```

with:

```
const decoded = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encoded));
```

**EDIT**:

Reading base64 data from file is another problem. The data imported from the file with the `encoding` option set to `base64` does guarantee a string instead of a buffer but it expects the input to be `utf-8` encoding the base64 string again (double encoding).

To fix this, change the following:

```
const encoded = fs.readFileSync("./base64.txt", { encoding: "base64" });
```

to:

```
const encoded = fs.readFileSync("./base64.txt").toString();
```

Comment: Why do I get the exact same result as in the data.txt file I don't get it?

Comment: @Ethanolle I guess you meant 2pac.txt. It should work now with the new edit.

Comment: Error: Malformed UTF-8 data i get back this error if im doing it tht way

Comment: Please ensure the data in base64.txt is a valid base64 string. The error indicates it is not a valid base64 text. In case it is, please share your input and expected output to debug.

Comment: I will soon is there a way that I talk to you in private?